# Div container shows wrong width and overlaps second container

Tags: html, css, containers, nav, overlap

As can be seen here (please make it wider): http://jsfiddle.net/CZayc/1368/, I wanted to make my navbar width 100% of browser width, and place some links (`First Second Third Fourth`) in the centered, 1200px wide space.

I do not know why, but the middle container just overlaps the navbar. 
Changing `position: absolute;` on navbar caused it to shrink to 1200px size (not desired).
What can I do about it? There is also a problem with `link` container, because I couldnt center `First Second Third Fourth` in the desired 1200px space (probably due to overlap).

Thanks!

Comment: I changed position to relative for the nav fixed it for me and did not shrink the width.

Answer (score 0):

Using absolute position on an element takes it out of the content flow: meaning that other elements in the flow act like its not there. The elements overlap because there is nothing to push the middle content down below the header.

There are 2 things you could do:

1. stop using position absolute. as @NendoTaka suggests, relative should be fine. If there is some reason for absolute positioning you haven't explained, then
2. add a margin to the middle content area.

Example CSS

```
.middle {
    background-color: #7f7f7f;
    height: 1050px;
    margin: 74px auto 0; /* height of nav plus its borders*/
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but changing the `:absolute` to `:relative` shrinks my navbar to body size (1200px), thats why I used it. What are my other options then? Should I use margin?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can move .middle out of the way by adding `margin-top`: https://jsfiddle.net/CZayc/1371/

Be sure to set `margin-top` to the height of .nav. This includes borders, too.

Answer (score 0):

Change your nav class to

```
.nav {
    background-color: #34384A;
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid;
    border-bottom: solid;
}
```

Note: You don't need the `width: 100%` but just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply position:relative to both the .nav and the .middle

Your problem before was that .nav had an absolute position which caused the overlap. the relative positioning keeps that from happening because it formats each div relative to the previous div as written in your HTML.

```
.nav {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #34384A;
    height: 70px;
    /* position: absolute; */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border-top: solid;
    border-bottom: solid;
    }

.middle {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #7f7f7f;
    height: 1050px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re trying to solve the wrong problem with your question. The example below is a cleaned up version of your code.

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0 }

nav {
  background-color: #34384A;
  height: 70px;
  border-top: solid;
  border-bottom: solid;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>Test test</header>

<nav>
  <a>First</a>
  <a>Second</a>
  <a>Third</a>
  <a>Foruth</a>
</nav>

<div class="middle">
 11111<br>22222<br>33333<br>44444<br>55555<br>66666
</div>

<footer>Test</footer>
```

Be mindful of the HTML you use. The HTML tags you choose should provide meaning to the content they wrap. Also you should avoid using `position: absolute` for general layout concerns such as this one.

Hope that helps.